# Date Conversion of one Timezone to different timezone

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I have a date say `2011-09-26T21:00:00Z` . I'm not sure what is `T` and `Z` in the date meant. This is `EET` time. I need to convert this to local time 'IST'.

Expected O/P : `2011-09-27T00:30:00Z` ( since we have 3 hours 30 minutes difference b/w EET and IST. Even `2011-09-27 00:30:00` or `2011-09-27`(at the least case) is ok for me.

I'm trying the below query But getting error as  `TimeZone region not found`

```
select to_char((from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                                           ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ,'EET')
       at time zone 'IST'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM TZD') as localtime
       from dual;
```

Somebody pls suggest any other ways to convert.

**UPDATE**:
I have tried the below query. It is giving output. But that is not the desired format.

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TO_CHAR((to_timestamp('2011-09-26 21:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')),
                      'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')||' Europe/Berlin',
                      'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss tzr') AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta' ts_eet 
          from dual;
```

*OUTPUT*: `27-SEP-11 12.30.00.000000000 AM ASIA/CALCUTTA` . Here i have one problem 1) I dont want `SEP` in month instead i need only `09` and the format should be same like `2011-09-27`

Comment: Won't a date in September be EEST rather than EET ([in most places](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/eet))? Do you have a region you can assign to the source timestamp, rather than EET? But the 'Z' in the string is supposed to mean it's [a UTC time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) so something is already wrong...

Comment: I have update the latest query with region. Now i'm getting the output but that is not in the required format can u please say how to convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle treats EET as a time zone region name (`SELECT tzname, tzabbrev FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE tzname = 'EET'`, or see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#i637736)) so it handles daylight saving/summer time (EEST/EEDT). On 2011-09-26 the EET *region* [was actually EEST](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?pl=1&lid=13,100,1275004&h=13&date=9/26/2011%7C3) so it was three hours ahead of UTC, not two; and as IST is always +05:30 the offset was actually +02:30. So your result is 'correct'.

Rather than bounce back and forth to a string, you can use the `from_tz` function to change a plain timestamp into a timestamp with time zone; and then `at time zone` to get that in a different zone:

```
select to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') orig_ts,
  from_tz(to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),
    'EET') orig_tsz,
  sys_extract_utc(from_tz(to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),
    'EET')) orig_utc,
  from_tz(to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),
    'EET') at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta' new_tsz
from dual;

ORIG_TS             ORIG_TSZ                          ORIG_UTC            NEW_TSZ                         
------------------- -------------------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------
2011-09-26 21:00:00 2011-09-26 21:00:00 EET    2011-09-26 18:00:00 2011-09-26 23:30:00 ASIA/CALCUTTA
```

The 'T' in your original string denotes the time, and the 'Z' denotes (or is supposed to!) that this represents a date/time in UTC; this is [the ISO 8601 standard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC). Oracle's conversion functions allow you to [embed character literals in the format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements004.htm#sthref406) to ignore those. Since it has a 'Z' you should be treating it as UTC not EET, so you might want to go back to whoever you're getting these values from.

If you really do expect all the values to be from the EET timezone with no summer time offset then you *could* use a fixed TZH:TZM rather than a region name:

```
select to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') orig_ts,
  from_tz(to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),
    '+02:00') orig_tsz,
  sys_extract_utc(from_tz(to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),
    '+02:00')) orig_utc,
  from_tz(to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'),
    '+02:00') at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta' new_tsz
from dual;

ORIG_TS             ORIG_TSZ                          ORIG_UTC            NEW_TSZ                         
------------------- -------------------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------
2011-09-26 21:00:00 2011-09-26 21:00:00 +02:00 2011-09-26 19:00:00 2011-09-27 00:30:00 ASIA/CALCUTTA
```

I doubt that is actually what you want but you'll need to clarify your requirements.

Finally to get the converted value back into the original format you need to use `to_char`:

```
select to_char(from_tz(to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z',
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'), 'EET') at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') new_string
from dual;

NEW_STRING        
-------------------
2011-09-26 23:30:00
```

You can embed the 'T' back in with `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'`; adding the 'Z' back onto the end seems wrong though.

If your source time is from Berlin as your question edit suggests (which is CET/CEST, not EET/EEST; gaining you that missing hour) just change the `from_tz` region:

```
select to_char(from_tz(to_timestamp('2011-09-26T21:00:00Z',
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'), 'Europe/Berlin') at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta',
    'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') new_string
from dual;

NEW_STRING        
-------------------
2011-09-27T00:30:00
```